# How do I display image from MongoDB using Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I have images in my mongo atlas DB and I need to retrieve them from the server and display them dynamically to the client using React.

How do I get the image data from mongo DB using mongoose and display that image dynamically to the client side. (Note: I want to save the image and load it dynamically in another component.

The problem is the constructor function of getting the image, that is the code on the very top ***(exports.getImagePost)*** and it is also in the react client where the http is passing the id for the preview image ***(const GetPostVerse = ({ match }) => {)***. Also I have tried to upload it to storage with NPM multer and it doesn't store the image in DB, it just shows it on the client end. Note: the image is saved properly in the DB

I have attempted to write a constructer that will be my function to get the image by id from the DB and render it on the client side, and I am not seeing the image:

Here is the code to get the image from server

```js
exports.getImagePost = async (req, res) => {
  // get id from URL by using req.params
  let ImageID = req.params.id;
  // we use mongodb's findById() functionality here
  await VImage.findByOne({ id: ImageID }, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).json({
        message: "Something went wrong, please try again later.",
      });
    } else {
      console.log(image);
      res.status(200).json({
        message: "Image found",
        data,
        image
      });
    }
  });
};
```

Here are my routes

```js
    router.post('/postverse', ivpostController.imagePost);//post image
    router.post('/createpostverse', ivpostController.createBibleVerse); //post bible verse
    router.get('/getimage/:id', ivpostController.getImagePost)//get image 
    router.get('/getverse/:id', ivpostController.getBibleVersePost); //get bible verse by id
```

Here is client side code the collects the data from user when user fills inputs and chooses bk-img

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {useHistory} from "react-router-dom";
import { isExpired, decodeToken } from "react-jwt";
import Container from "react-bootstrap/Container";
import Card from "react-bootstrap/Card";
// import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
// import "./postverse.css";
import axios from "axios";

const GetPostVerse = ({ match }) => {
  const [body, setBody] = useState("");
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const history = useHistory();
  // const [id, setId] = useState("");
  const [imagePreview, setImagePreview] = useState(
    `http://localhost:5000/getimage/${match.params.id}`
  );

  const loadData = async () => {
    try {
      let res = await axios.get(
        `http://localhost:5000/getverse/${match.params.id}`
      );
      setTitle(res.data.data.title);
      // console.log(res.data);
      // console.log(res.data.data.title);
      // console.log(match.params.id);
      setBody(res.data.data.body);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // console.log("use effect working!");
    if (!window.localStorage.getItem("token")) {
      //redirect to login
      console.log("redirect to login");
      history.push("/");
    }
    if (window.localStorage.getItem("token")) { 
      const isMyTokenExpired = isExpired(window.localStorage.getItem("token"));
      console.log(isMyTokenExpired);

      if(isMyTokenExpired) {
        console.log("redirect to login");
        history.push("/");
      }

      const myDecodedToken = decodeToken(window.localStorage.getItem("token"));
      console.log(myDecodedToken);
    }
    loadData()
  });
// },[]);

  return (
    <div className="getpostverse">
      <Container className="mt-5 ml-auto mr-auto">
        <h1 className="text-center">
          ShareVerse
          <span className="text-success"> Saved Posts</span>
        </h1>

        <div>saved image</div>
        <div>
          <div className="shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded">
            <Card className="bg-dark shadow text-white">
              <Card.Img src={imagePreview} alt="Card image" />
              <Card.ImgOverlay>
                <Card.Title className="text-center mt-5">
                  <h1 className="text-warning">{title}</h1>
                </Card.Title>
                <Card.Title className="text-center mt-5">
                  <h3 className="text-warning">{body}</h3>
                </Card.Title>
              </Card.ImgOverlay>
            </Card>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
};

// test link: http://localhost:3000/getverse/6021ef044a42be4388eee4ed

export default GetPostVerse;
```

this is the error i get, instead of dark gray I need the image to be there
[image]

Comment: There is a lot of code here and no hints as to which part of the process fails. What I recommend is you to debug the issue a little more and come back with a "slimmer" question, some of the questions you should have an answer to are: 
1. is the image saved properly in the DB?
2. can you read the image in code and save it into a working (png?) file?
3. is the findById working properly? it looks like you're using `string` and not `ObjectId` in your route

Comment: I will add that there is a lot of network overhead due to passing the image back and forth. A more "best practice" solution would be to upload the image to storage (like s3) and in Mongo just save the mapping to the endpoint of it. when a user want's to read it it's a simple findOne.

Comment: @TomSlabbaert Thank you for your response. The problem is the constructor function of getting the image, that is the code on the very top ***(exports.getImagePost)*** and it is also in the react client where the http is passing the id for the preview image ***(const GetPostVerse = ({ match }) => {)***. Also I have tried to upload it to storage with NPM multer and but it doesn't store the img in db, it just shows it on the client end

Yes the img is saved proper in the db
what do you mean by can i read the img in code and save it to a working file?
how would i use an objID in the route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the answer: I had to get image from object id :
[image]

Then i had to add an axios http request on the client side and pass function into useEffect()
[image]